# Solve for θ $\csc 3θ = 5 \sin 3\theta$

Tags: trigonometry

Solve for $θ$, find all solutions.

$\csc 3θ = 5 \sin 3θ$

I get stuck when I do this:

$$\frac{1}{\sin 3θ} = 5\sin3θ$$

$$\frac{1}{5} = (\sin 3θ)^2$$

How do I simplify the right side?

Answer (score 2):

You'd get $\frac{1}{5} = \sin^2{(3\theta)}$, solving for $\theta$ you can obtain $\sin{(3\theta)} = \pm \frac{\sqrt{5}}{5} \implies \theta = \frac{\pi n}{3} \pm \frac{\arcsin{(\frac{\sqrt{5}}{5}})}{3}$.

You can then use the above to find all our solutions in what I'd assume is the interval $[0,2\pi)$.

Comment: Thank you, but why is it $+\frac{\pi n}{3}$ and not $+\frac{2\pi n}{3}$

Comment: Because the solutions of $\sin{(3\theta)}=0$ are multiples of $\frac{\pi}{3}$, in our case we have it equal to one fifth, which is why we get the complications with arcsin and it is squared, so the plus or minus.

Comment: I got $0.1545+ \frac{\pi k}{3}$, $-0.1545+ \frac{\pi k}{3}$, $2.987+ \frac{\pi k}{3}$, $3.296+ \frac{\pi k}{3}$,Did I make a mistake somewhere?

Comment: (Add a space in there for the pi.) The first two I agree with, not sure where you get 2.987 and 3.296.

Comment: I found like the alternative reference angles by doing $ 2\pi - 0.1545$ and $\pi + 0.1545$

Comment: Ah, yes, I'm unused to using decimals for such, but I believe that should be accurate. Keep in mind you're going to get round off errors for checking those solutions as decimals by the way.

Answer (score 1):

We have $$\sin^23\theta=\frac{1}{5}=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\right)^2$$  Let, $\frac{1}{\sqrt5}=\sin \alpha$ $$ \sin^23\theta=\sin^2\alpha$$ Now, writing the general solution for $\theta$ as follows  $$3\theta=n\pi\pm\alpha$$$$=n\pi\pm\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt5}\right)$$ $$\bbox[5px, border:2px solid #C0A000]{\color{red}{\theta=\frac{n\pi}{3}\pm \frac{1}{3}\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt5}\right)}}$$
Where, $n$ is any integer.